# How to add on text from a certain XML file onto text boxes

Tags: c#, xml

So I'm currently working on a project right now involving C-Sharp, and it it frustrating me so much. Currently, I have to get text stored in a XML tag, read it as a string, and store it into a series of text boxes. However, for some reason, the text boxes keep nullifying each other out; they are erasing each other. What am I doing wrong? It's been bugging for a while now. Thank you!

```
        XmlDocument generalXML = new XmlDocument();
        generalXML.Load(generalURI);

        // Connect to the web request for the resource you want
        // In other words - create a socket with the uri

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(generalURI);

        // Indicate that you will READ only (GET)
        req.Method = "GET";

        try
        {
            // get and store the response and convert it into a usable stream
            HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            Stream str = res.GetResponseStream();

            // read the stream as an XML object
            XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(str);

            if (textBoxDescription.Text == "")
            {
                xr.ReadToFollowing("description");
                textBoxDescription.Text = xr.ReadElementContentAsString();
            }

            if (textBoxWebsite.Text == "")
            {
                xr.ReadToFollowing("website");
                textBoxWebsite.Text = xr.ReadElementContentAsString();
            }

            if (textBoxEmail.Text == "")
            {
                xr.ReadToFollowing("email");
                textBoxEmail.Text = xr.ReadElementContentAsString();
            }

            if (textBoxName.Text == "")
            {
                xr.ReadToFollowing("name");
                textBoxName.Text = xr.ReadElementContentAsString();
            }

            // close the ocnnection to the resource
            res.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.Write("Error");
        }
```

Comment: Btw, you probably don't want to print messages to `Console` in WinForms :) Can you give us the `generalURI`?

Comment: the generalURI is this: 
string generalURI = @"http://simon.ist.rit.edu:8080/Services/resources/ESD/" + orgID + "/General";

Comment: and noted, thanks. this is just something quick I've been working on.

Comment: if it's not a problem, you you post here also the `orgID`? I would try your code on my machine to determine what's wrong. I don't see any problem right now.

Comment: well, the orgID is dynamically generated...

Comment: but I'll just give you the orgID of 1 for now.

Comment: Ok, currently, it throws an exception on this line `generalXML.Load(generalURI);` saying that `The URI prefix is not recognized.`

Comment: I think there is some problem with the generalURI yes:

It should be like:

`@"simon.ist.rit.edu:8080/Services/resources/ESD/" + orgID + "/General"`

Comment: @OndrejJanacek: it works fine for me on my machine right now

Comment: @DanielAshfallZhou I can't help you with it any further, the resource is not available for me.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek: here you got then: http://simon.ist.rit.edu:8080/Services/resources/ESD/Organizations

Comment: You want to display all the info from a document or just for the first element you find there?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek I have a datagridview that outputs all the organizations (it's a search engine). I click on a particular result and a 2nd form pops up with the information about the organization.

Answer (score 1):

OK here is what is get from your question:

First of all your URI is not written correctly.

```
@"simon.ist.rit.edu:8080/Services/resources/ESD/"; + orgID + "/General";
```

**change it to:** `(@"simon.ist.rit.edu:8080/Services/resources/ESD/" + orgID + "/General"`

Secondly i think the textboxes are not filled correctly they are not nullifying each other.
try:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(@"http://simon.ist.rit.edu:8080/Services/resources/ESD/Organizations");
XmlNode OrganizationID= document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/data/row/OrganizationID");
string type= document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/data/row/type").InnerText.ToString();
string Name= document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/data/row/Name").InnerText.ToString();
string Email= document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/data/row/Email").InnerText.ToString();
string city= document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/data/row/city").InnerText.ToString();
string zip= document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/data/row/zip").InnerText.ToString();
string CountyName= document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/data/row/CountyName").InnerText.ToString();
string State= document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/data/row/State").InnerText.ToString();
```

Comment: wait, that semicolon in the URI shouldn't be there... It's not in my initial code.
and nope, that didn't work...

Comment: @DanielAshfallZhou Anyway, do use that Http detritus in your code, just XmlDocument and use it as DOT_NET Junior shows you and you should be fine.

Comment: no, but that semicolon isn't in my initial code; I don't know how it ended up here. And it didn't work...

Comment: @DanielAshfallZhou given your xml on URL :
http://simon.ist.rit.edu:8080/Services/resources/ESD/Organizations

I cannot see there is description Node.

Comment: the description is part of the xml you get from accessing a specific organization

Comment: @DanielAshfallZhou Check my updated code. It is just for first Organization.

Comment: wait, so how do I put this into the specific text box?
and for the for xmlnode, I need a name, type is already specified when searched. I'm assuming to get name, you need "/data/row/name"?

Comment: @DanielAshfallZhou to put the in textbox,
simply change you line:

textBoxEmail.Text = Email;

Comment: @DanielAshfallZhou I have update code more, Please accept it as answer if it helped you thanks.

Comment: ahhh it doesn't work...

here are the xml tags I need to get for the General Information though:

 <name\>
   <email\>
   <website\>
   <description\>
   <nummembers\>
   <numcalls\>
   <serviceArea\>